# iTerm2 does not take the focus with the hotkey window

Tags: iterm

I have setup a new Mac with iTerm and the hotkey window shortcut (MacOS Catalina).

It all works well, except that the hotkey window does not take the focus when it opens. I mean that I can type commands rightaway, but the active application does not change.

E.g. **if I am in Firefox and hit the shortcut, then the Firefox menus are still active.**

The problem with that is that my IDE (Intellij) does not register that the focus changed to another app, and does not save file changes or refresh files from disk, which makes programming very difficult.

I know it used to work on my former machine. I suspect I need to configure iTerm correctly.

Here is how the hotkey shortcut is configured:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This one had me too. Just untick "Floating window" and restart iTerm2.

Full directions:

- MENU: iterm2
- MENU ITEM: Preferences...
- TAB: Profiles
- LIST ITEM: [Your Hotkey Profile Name]
- TAB: Keys
- BUTTON: Configure Hotkey Window
- CHECKBOX: Floating Window <= UNCHECK THIS

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did have to check an extra checkbox in "Advanced": "The hotkey window floats above other windows", else the hotkey window wasn't visible.

Comment: thank you guys Mike and @MatthieuNapoli, you saved my day, was trying to figure out that long time

Comment: i dont see that as a solution because then you lose the terminal when you click on other displays.

Comment: @dtc I believe you're looking for "Pin hotkey window." It's pictured in the screenshot above.

Comment: Big thanks for providing this simple fix! It saved me a lot of hassle trying to find other workarounds.

Comment: @MikeStopContinues But Pin Hotkey window does not keep the window on top, it goes behind other open windows, not sure how to fix that